# getting input from kivy textinput

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I want to use this for a later project, I just want to print user's input from the `TextInput` by clicking the button on the `MainScreen`, but when I run and click on the button with the text "Print Text" nothing happens no errors and no output.

The .kv file:

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    Button:
        on_release: root.get_text
        text: "Print Text"
        font_size: 50
        size_hint:0.3,0.1

    TextInput:
        text:"Hello World"
        size_hint: 0.35,0.25
        pos_hint:{"right":1, "top":1}
        color:1,0,0,1
        id: user_text

    Button:
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 25
            size_hint: 0.3,0.25
            text: "Continue"
            on_release: app.root.current = "other"
            pos_hint:{"right":1, "top":0}


<SecondScreen>:
    name: "other"
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            color: 0,1,0,1
            font_size: 25
            size_hint: 0.3,0.25
            text: "Back Home"
            on_release: app.root.current = "main"
            pos_hint:{"right":1, "top":1}
```

The python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
#kivy.require("1.9.1")
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen , FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def get_text(self,*args):
        textinput= self.ids.user_text
        user=  TextInput.text
        print(user)



class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


gui = Builder.load_file("main.kv")


class MainApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return gui


MainApp().run()
```

Comment: In get_text you do ´TextInput.text´ instead of ´textinput.text´.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you code in `kv`, you bind directly as if you'd *call* the function e.g.

```
on_release: do_this()
```

but you did it without parenthesis as if it was a casual python binding:

```
self.bind(on_release=do_this)
```

Add the parenthesis and it should print:

```
on_release: root.get_text()
```